# How to display value of a checkbox in p:datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `<p:datatable>` and one of my columns has `<p:column selection="multiple">`. This column value is one of the attributes of my entity class called Role. So when I check one of the value it goes to the backing bean and updates the value of that Role from false to true. Now when I go back to the page since the value of that attribute for that particular role is `true` I want the check box to be selected.

Could anyone let me know how I can do it? All the value in the table come from the database, I tried adding `<h:outputText value="#{role.active}">` where role is my value of `var` in my `<p:datatable>` and `active` is the boolean field in that entity class.

```xml
<p:column selectionMode="multiple">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Active"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

Have a `h:commandButton` which send this values to the bean . All that is working fine but when I load the table I want the value of check box to be checked it the active value is true. Can I use something like `<h:outputtext value="#{role.active}"/>`.This did not work for me.

Comment: I don't get what your problem is, as you provided insufficient information. Do you have a `<h/p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{role.active}">`? Doesn't it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The datatable's `selection` attribute has to bind to your selection in the backing bean. So you've to fill correctly this binding with the active roles, for example in the `@PostConstruct` of your backing bean.

```xml
<p:dataTable value="#{backingBean.roles}" selection="#{backingBean.selectedRoles}" var="role">
```

### See also

- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Comment: Though the question is much unclear, how does your post even loosely answers OP's question?

Comment: I do not have <h/p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{role.active}">. For creating a check box in primefaces I have used <p:column selection="multiple">. I have edited the question with the code that i have used. Let me know how I can use it.Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Did you try what I'm proposing?